# Django: How to change to success message for update_object?

Tags: django

I'm using the django messages framework for user notifications and `update_object` to handle saving of forms. When a form is successfully posted the default message is `[MyModel] successfully saved` or similar.

I want to change this message to a custom one ("Your changes were saved"), either for all form posts or for every use of update_object.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: In terms of grammar - "Your change was saved" should be "Your changes were saved" or "Your change was saved".

Comment: @Dominic: you mean "your _change_ was saved", don't you?

Comment: örn - are you talking about from Django's admin interface, or from a particular view? I'm assuming you're talking about Django's admin interface (since it was just a view you wrote yourself you have to generate that message yourself, at which point this change becomes trivial). If you are talking about Django's admin interface, I don't think this is possible without monkey-patching Django.

Comment: Yep - that message is defined in the guts of django.contrib.admin (see http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L677).

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you are talking about the `update_object` [generic view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-create-update-update-object).

If that is the case then there is no way (hook) to change the success message at present (Django 1.2.3). You can see this for yourself in the [source code](http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/django/views/generic/create_update.py). Just look for `update_object`.

One rather flaky way to do this would be to use a custom `post_save_redirect` and render the message yourself. The `post_save_redirect` can be a simple view to display the appropriate success message. This will mean losing the redirection to the object's permalink though.

You can also try adding a custom message (using `messages.success`) and then redirect to the saved object's permalink in the wrapper. I haven't tried this myself so I do not know how this will turn out.